# FtpWebRequest can't handle filenames that start with dash or dot

Tags: c#, ftp

I am creating an ftp based utility with c# .net 4 with a backend filezilla server. It works fine until my depth search meets a folder starting with (-) dash or (.) dot. I researched the net a bit, found out you cannot have filenames starting with dash or dot in ftp for reasons I understood. I tried encoding the uri as suggested changing "." with "%2E" and "-" with "%2D" and - with ./- without any improvement (in step by step debugging I saw it change succesfully but filezilla server logged a 550 error), HttpUtilities.UriEncoding gave me the same result. Very strange behaviour though as it seems ftp LISTS the parent directory of the asked one. So for example when I try to LIST the directory /games/-randomdir I get the list of /games again resulting to a new false uri of the depth search /games/-randomdir/-randomdir! See for yourself the server's interface answer:

```
(127.0.0.1)> CWD /
(127.0.0.1)> 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
(127.0.0.1)> CWD a00000001/game
(127.0.0.1)> 250 CWD successful. "/a00000001/game" is current directory.
(127.0.0.1)> PASV
(127.0.0.1)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,194,205)
(127.0.0.1)> LIST -eclipse
(127.0.0.1)> 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/a00000001/game"
(127.0.0.1)> 226 Successfully transferred "/a00000001/game"
```

It succesfully transfers the content of game, not -eclipse which LIST asks. 
That is because LIST -eclipse is perfectly valid (although not existing) command for the emulated server. So it LISTS again "games" with the extra command "eclipse". But, how can I escape it?

Comment: In addition, with windows ftp I could replicate the exact same problem by using the command dir -eclipse. FTP answered with current folder's items although using dir ./-eclipse showed me the correct results. This doesn't happen though in FtpWebRequest. Another solution would be to CWD to -eclipse dir and THEN ask for LIST. Although FtpWebRequest has another opinion over this, and asks LIST -eclipse from parent dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this! It's hacky but works. On your URI you need to add a last slash "/" so the FTP will change folder before listing like this!

```
Uri u = new Uri("ftp://" + ip.ToString() + (folder) + "/", UriKind.Absolute);
```